# Are missing drivers causing performance issues on my server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, dell-poweredge

Apparently i have been experiencing slowness on my server:Dell power edge 2970. when am copying large data file from the C to external drive.I have upgraded my ram and do a check disk.The problem still persist.Is there any special driver am missing that is causing this performance bottleneck?

Comment: whats the external disk usb2/3 esata etc?

Comment: Am using usb drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're maxing out I/O when doing copies, so that's probably why. It'd be like benchmarking your computer then wondering why a game is running slow.

As for your answer, get faster disks or RAID.

Comment: ,am trying some sata drivers first, if that did not work i can try your suggestion.